# How can I sum specific elements of an array in python

Tags: python, performance, memory-efficient

There is a simple operation that I need to do a few hundred times with very large arrays (thousands of elements), so I need the most efficient solution (for-loops are too slow):

I have two arrays e.g.

```
a = np.array([1,23,25,100,100,101])
b = np.array([1,2,2,3,4,4])
```

I would now like to get the sums of all elements in a for which b has the same value.
i.e.

```
[1,48,100,201]
```

I could do:

```
#first index of each unique entry in b
u = np.unique(b,return_index=True)[1]
#split array and sum
list(map(sum, np.split(a,u[1:])))
```

But that's a bit slow, and it only works if the entries in b are sorted. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: `np.bincount(b-1, a)` or `np.bincount(b, a)` containing the binned sums at index `[bin]`.

Comment: Yes, that's actually exactly what I meant! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
>>> [a[b==n].sum() for n in np.unique(b)]
[1, 48, 100, 201]
```

If you're open to using `pandas`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({"a": a, "b": b}).groupby("b").sum()["a"].tolist()
[1, 48, 100, 201]
```

Comment: I could also solve the problem like this: 

import pandas as pd ; 
df = pd.DataFrame() ;
df["a"] = a ;
df["b"] = b ;
df.groupby(["b"])["a"].agg("sum") ;

but I thought there might be a simpler/faster way

Comment: There was no `pandas` tag to your post, hence my suggested solution. If not, you could just do `df.groupby("a")["b"].sum()`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I don't mind using pandas if that's the most efficient way.

Comment: @MarthaMuller - See the edit!